# What technology this site uses for route searching?

Tags: google-maps, routes

My old town's local transportation company has a new site, a very nice one.
http://www.tpltm.ro/en/

There is a search for public means of transportation, also supporting transit between different means of transportation.
Try these data for testing:
 Departure: `Spitalul Judetean`
 Arrival: `Strada Pacii (Posta Mare)`

It also supports autocompletion. Then the map is shown with the route and the stations as layers on top of Google Maps. Another nice thing is the way map scrolls when the object below the mouse cursor is not inside the viewable area. Also the nice animation with placing the infoboxes (falling from the top of the page).

Does anyone know how it is done? I would like to make somethig relatively similar for different custom routes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they are using [this](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html) because when you get the source from that page with the map you see this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>` on the link I provided you see this:Tracking Usage with the sensor Parameter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it is somehow using Google Maps API, but I don't know how to search between pre-defined tracks (buses, trams, troleybuses), each with their stations (they are on a custom layer I guess).

Comment: Then your better of with [link] http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/places but I think they just have a databank where all lines are in and they get a arrival and destination and they see if there's a bus stop nearby and then show a route generated with google maps.